# Set values in json file (using karate intuit framework)

Tags: json, karate

I need to pass values from my features to json files.
Ex: an item is created in the test feature and id is returned in response;
I would like to put this id in a json file where I have something as:
{`"item":
    ["string1", string2 etc..]`
}
  to concatenate the id in string1, string2

I saw an example here but it didn't help me for json files:
https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/demos/type-conv.feature

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`set`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#set) keyword:

```
* def json = read('some.json')
* set json.item[] = 'string3'
```